# Rails: Easy way to add more than one flash[:notice] at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought every time you do a `flash[:notice]="Message"` it would add it to the array which would then get displayed during the view but the following just keeps the last flash:

```
flash[:notice] = "Message 1"
flash[:notice] = "Message 2"
```

Now I realize it's just a simple hash with a key (I think :)) but is there a better way to do multiple flashes than the following:

```
flash[:notice] = "Message 1<br />"
flash[:notice] << "Message 2"
```

Comment: Beware the cookie overflow.

Comment: @Ziggy YES! Thank you. I ran into this last week so your timing is ace. I ended up changing to an `ActiveRecord` session store to handle larger session data, as per: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `flash` message can really be anything you want, so you could do something like this:

```
flash[:notice] = ["Message 1"]
flash[:notice] << "Message 2"
```

And then in your views, output it as

```
<%= flash[:notice].join("<br>") %>
```

Or whatever you prefer.

Whether that technique is *easier* than other solutions is determined by your own preferences.

Comment: In Rails 3, the `<br>` will be escaped unless marked as safe. Try [safe_join](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/safe_join): `<%= safe_join(flash[:notice], "<br>".html_safe) %>`. Also note that individual flash items are usually just strings. mipadi is using [square brackets] around the instantiation to create an array instead. Without those brackets, the `<<` just appends more text to the string.

Comment: Afaik it gets overwritten then if you do `redirect_to path, notice: 'where is it gone?'` - so this is a solution to be careful with.

Answer (score 64):

I usually add such methods to my ApplicationHelper:

```
def flash_message(type, text)
    flash[type] ||= []
    flash[type] << text
end
```

And

```
def render_flash
  rendered = []
  flash.each do |type, messages|
    messages.each do |m|
      rendered << render(:partial => 'partials/flash', :locals => {:type => type, :message => m}) unless m.blank?
    end
  end
  rendered.join('<br/>')
end
```

And after it is very easy to use them:

You can write something like:

```
flash_message :notice, 'text1'
flash_message :notice, 'text2'
flash_message :error, 'text3'
```

in your controller.

And just add this line to your layout:

```
<%= render_flash %>
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, that's a more thorough answer. I suppose one can make it as robust as needed. I'm still a little surprised this isn't built into the core - seems like an obvious requirement (as I type this I have three 'flash'-like notifications coming from Stack Overflow (i.e. new badge, associate my account, etc.) ;)

Comment: A good answer. However, there are two problems: the `flash.now` method and the possibility of giving a flash message as an extra parameter in a `redirect_to` call. The first can be handled by giving the `flash_message` method a third (possibly optional) boolean parameter; if `true` is given as its value, the method should use the `flash.now` array instead of that of `flash`. (The one initialization to an empty array is sufficient.) The second problem is taken care of simply by setting the flash message on a separate line before the call of `redirect_to` instead of using the extra parameter.

Comment: I would use this as an alternate first line of flash_message to ensure it is an array.
      `flash[type] = *flash[type]`

Comment: @TeemuLeisti thanks for your `flash.now` suggestion. Although in my case I found that the one initialization to an empty array _wasn't_ sufficient. I needed `flash.now[type] ||= []` if true, and `flash[type] ||= []` if false (i.e. not "now"). I'm using Rails 5.2.

Comment: @Victor I highly recommend adjusting `messages.each do |m|` to become `Array.wrap(messages).each do |m|`. This makes any existing flash messages to be backwards compatible which is helpful for 2 reasons. 1. There's less refactoring of all your existing flash messages (you should only need to replace when you need multiple messages). 2. It will ensure that any gems which add flash messages don't cause exceptions, e.g. [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) or [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) which manage user authentication and commonly add flash messages.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75844657/824806) is a recap.

Answer (score 5):

I think the idea built into the framework is that every message you stick into flash is over-writeable. You give each message a unique key so you can change or overwrite it.

If you need another message, don't call it ":notice." Call each something unique. Then to render the flash messages, loop through whatever is in the hash.

If this doesn't work for you, consider whether you actually need to simplify your UI.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with Jonathan in that the UI might need some simplification, there are instances where you might want to display multiple messages for the same key.

As a result, I have created a gem that (should) make it easy to deal with multiple flash messages in the same key and their rendering in the view.

GitHub:
[flash-dance](http://github.com/MunkiPhD/flash-dance)

Answer (score 1):

On Rails 4.1 this will not work. I have a different implementation, so I think your code should be changed this way:

```
def render_flash
  rendered = []
  flash.keys do |type|
    flash[type].each do |m|
      rendered << render(:partial => 'partials/flash', :locals => {:type => type, :message => m}) unless m.blank?
    end
  end
  rendered.join('<br/>')
end
```

Comment: Is `flash[name]` suppose to be `flash[type]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recap extracted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2452899) and subsequent comments.

In app/helpers/application_helper.rb file, add this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_message(type, message, now = false)
    f = now ? flash.now : flash
    f[type] ||= []
    f[type] << message
  end

  def render_flash_messages
    rendered = []
    flash.each do |type, messages|
      Array.wrap(messages).each do |m|
        rendered << render(:partial => 'path/to/flash_messages', :locals => {:type => type, :message => m}) unless m.blank?
      end
    end
    rendered.join('<br/>')
  end
end
```

In controller files:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    helpers.flash_message(:success, "Some text")
  end
end
```

In view files:

```
<%= sanitize(render_flash_messages) %>
```

The *downside* is that to use helpers from controllers (Rails 5+) you have to use the [`helpers`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html#method-i-helpers) object, [which may be a design issue](https://www.rubyguides.com/2020/01/rails-helpers/).

Answer (score 0):

A method on how to use both 'traditional' one-liner messages and array-style for messages with line breaks.

With Rails 4.1 and the JSON serializer, you can use one-liner flash messages

```
flash[:notice] = 'message'
```

and multi-line flash messages

flash[:notice] = ['message line 1', 'message line 2']

like so (in `application.html.haml` or the appropriate template file)

```
- if notice
   #css_class 
   = safe_join(Array(notice), '<br/>'.html_safe)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add flash messages in your application you just need to flow these steps.

Add a _flash_messages.html.erb file and add this code in it.

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(type) %> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And now call it in application.html.erb like add this line in application.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "shared/flash_messages", flash: flash %>
```

now add this code in application.helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

```
def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
  case flash_type
    when :success
      "alert-success"
    when :error
      "alert-error"
    when :alert
      "alert-block"
    when :notice
      "alert-info"
    else
      flash_type.to_s
  end
end
```

end

This will work for you hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstap 4, slim

```
.container.mt-3.full-max-width-down-md
  - flash.each do |key, value|
    div{class="alert alert-#{key} alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert"}
      button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
        i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"

      - if value.is_a? Array
        = safe_join(value, "<br />".html_safe)
      - else
        = value
```

Example

```
flash[:notice] = "Hey"
flash[:notice] = ["Hey", "Hey"]
redirect_to my_path, flash: { notice: "Hey" }
redirect_to my_path, flash: { notice: ["Hey", "Hey"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do multiple flash messages at a time without too much rigamarole, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197312/721065) as inspiration:

```rb
flash[:notice] = "#{flash[:notice]} Message 1<br />"
flash[:notice] = "#{flash[:notice]} Message 2"
```

Or

```rb
flash[:notice] = flash[:notice].to_s + 'Message 1<br />'
flash[:notice] = flash[:notice].to_s + 'Message 2'
```

Quote from the above-referenced answer:

> This works because NilClass defines a #to_s method that returns a zero-length String, and because instance variables are automatically initialized to nil.

Depending on circumstances, though not in the context of this posted question, you might have to deal with a trailing break tag or comma or whatever "delimeter" you're using. Which you could deal with a number of ways like [`chomp`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp)