# how to append a string to a variable that either exists or not?

Tags: ruby

my solution is like

```
if (not (defined?(@results).nil?))
  @results += "run"
else
  @results = "run"
end
```

but I believe that there is something simpler ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
@results = @results.to_s + "run"
```

This works because [`NilClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/NilClass.html) defines a `#to_s` method that returns a zero-length String, and because instance variables are automatically initialized to nil.

Comment: A variation of this would be `@results = "#{@results}run"`

Answer (score 12):

You're right:

```
(@results ||= "") << "run"
```

To clarify, `a || b` is `a ? a : b`, meaning that it tries to use the value `a` if `a` is "truthy" (not false or nil) but uses `b` if `a` is "falsey". Using `||=` hence only updates a variable if the variable is nil. Then, `<<` appends the string.

Comment: is that correct? `Using ||= hence only updates the variable @results if the variable is not nil. Otherwise it updates an empty string "". The update/append is done via  << .`

Comment: @Radek: Let me clarify further: because `a _= b` for some operator `_` becomes `a = a _ b`, we get (@results = @results || "") << "run".

Comment: @Radek: Note that this form is more idiomatic to Ruby as it is a generic pattern.

Comment: :-) I do not understand what you said :-)

Comment: @Radek: This is what people usually use to do this in Ruby.

Comment: This is the best solution here. Basically it means, if @results does not exist, make it, and set its value to to "". If it already exists, append "run" to it. If this is used in a loop, it will create the variable in first cycle of loop, than append values to it in every cycle (including first, right after creation).

Comment: It doesn't hurt to write two lines: `@result ||= ""; @result << "run"`. Much easier to understand IMO.