# Append to value if key is defined, declare if not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In the code below I'm trying to append text to a string value if a key is defined. If the key is not defined then it simply defines the key/value pair with the text.

```
if my_hash.key?(:my_key)
  my_hash[:my_key] << 'My text'
else
  my_hash[:my_key] = 'My text'
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try this: `my_hash[:my_key] = my_hash[:my_key].presence.to_s + 'My text'` : if `my_hash[:my_key]` is `nil`, it will call `nil.to_s`, which returns an empty String

Comment: No need for `presence`, you can use `my_hash[:my_key] = my_hash[:my_key].to_s + 'My text'`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196484/how-to-append-a-string-to-a-variable-that-either-exists-or-not)

Comment: Perfect! both solutions work so I guess the less verbose one is the better one. Why does this work though? would to_s give out an error if the key is not defined?

Comment: It works because `nil.to_s` becomes `""`

Comment: Check the above link. It's because `NilClass` has a `to_s` method that returns an empty string, and a missing hash key returns nil... `my_hash[:doesnt_exist] # => nil`. That's why there is no need for `presence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a hash that defaults to an empty string. Then, you do not have to take care of null values:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = '' }
hash[:key] << 'string'

puts hash
# => { :key => 'string' }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by MrYoshiji and Damien Roche the solution to the question is the following:

```
my_hash[:my_key] = my_hash[:my_key].to_s + 'My text'
```

Furthermore, if the text should be separated by a space in case `:my_key` was defined value this can be done:

```
my_hash[:my_key] = [ my_hash[:my_key].to_s, 'My text' ].reject(&:empty?).join(' ')
```

This could then be wrapped up in a helper function to make things a little easier:

```
def add_str(str, new_str)
  [str.to_s, new_str].reject(&:empty?).join(' ')
end

my_has[:my_key] = add_str my_has[:my_key], 'My text'
```