# Append suffix to string only if it is present (or not nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a concise way as an alternative to this

```
value = if my_var.present? # or .nil? I dont care
          "#{my_var} %"
        end
```

*Concise* meaning at least that no if statement is used and the variable is only written once.

Kind of like this question [how to append a string to a variable that either exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196484/how-to-append-a-string-to-a-variable-that-either-exists-or-not/6196496)

Just the other way around: When the value is not existing, then the string with the suffix makes no sense to show.

Comment: `value = "#{my_var} %" if my_var.present?`?

Comment: @mudasobwa a one-liner, but would not be usable in a hash literal for example

Comment: Excuse me? It has the exactly same application as @ndn’s answer.

Comment: I mean, I would be able to use
`"#{my_var} %" if my_var.present?` in a hash literal

Comment: I don’t get what’s the issue with using it in a hash literal. `{foo: (42 if false)}` ⇒ `{foo: nil}`.

Comment: Well, you're right. I did not think about wrapping the question in parentheses

Comment: @kluka _"would not be usable in a hash literal"_ – your question shows an assignment, it doesn't say anything about a hash literal.

Comment: I added a sentence to the question
"Concise meaning at least that no if statement is used and the variable is only written once."

Comment: _"[...] makes no sense to show"_ – sounds like this is _view_ related. Could you provide some context?

Comment: Well yes, it was shown to a user in the end (but not a rails view). The method that printed out the value in a hash was filtering any elements with nil values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string.presence&.concat('suffix')
```

In case you care for `nil`s only and not overall presence, you can simplify it:

```
string&.concat('suffix')
```

---

If you don't want to mutate the original value, you can instead do the somewhat cryptic:

```
string&.+('suffix')
```

Comment: Beware: no [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag.

Comment: @mudasobwa well yea, but OP used `#present?` in his original implementation, so...

Comment: yeah, I personally don't mind a active support dependency. Should I add the ruby-on-rails tag?

Comment: @kluka I added it.

Comment: Note that `concat` will mutate the receiver, you might want to use `+` instead.

Comment: I still remember how the mutating nature of `concat` did bite me later ;)

Answer (score 4):

Good old [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
'foo'.try(:+, ' %') #=> "foo %"
  nil.try(:+, ' %') #=> nil
```

or with a block:

```
'foo'.try { |s| "#{s} %" } #=> "foo %"
  nil.try { |s| "#{s} %" } #=> nil
```

In order to handle blank strings, you can just add `presence`:

```
' '.presence.try { |s| "#{s} %" } #=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
value = my_var && "#{my_var} %"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = my_var.dup.presence.tap { |s| s << " %" if s }
```

Comment: This will alter `my_var`.