# Custom validate doesn't appear to be adding errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to stop a user voting for themselves using validation.

Submitting a self vote renders the basic flash "Vote not accepted." but doesn't add the validation error "You cannot vote for your self".

How can I add the error to the flash?

In my model I have

```
class Imagevote < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :cannot_vote_for_self


    def cannot_vote_for_self
        if voter_id == voted_id
        errors.add(:base, "You cannot vote for your self")
        end
    end
end
```

In my controller I have

```
class ImagevotesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @imagevote = Imagevote.new(imagevote_params)
        @collection = Collection.find(params[:imagevote][:collection_id])
        @imagevote.voted_id = @collection.user_id
        if @imagevote.save
            flash[:success] = "Vote accepted."
            redirect_to @imagevote
        else
            flash[:success] = "Vote not accepted."
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    def update
        @imagevote = Imagevote.find(params[:id])
        @collection = Collection.find(params[:imagevote][:collection_id])
        @imagevote.voted_id = @collection.user_id
        if @imagevote.update_attributes(imagevote_params)
            flash[:success] = "Vote changed."
            redirect_to @imagevote
        else
        flash[:success] = "Vote not accepted."
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end
```

I think the errors are inserted here in my application layout view

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, raw(value), class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following

```
errors.add(:base, "You cannot vote for your self")
```

would add errors to an instance of Model `Imagevote`. They will not be added to `flash` hash.

In order to display the `validation error messages`, you need following code in

```
<% if @imagevote.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@imagevote.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @imagevote.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

in the view where you are `creating/updating` an `Imagevote` object.

**EDIT**

Update the `cannot_vote_for_self` validation method as below:

```
   def cannot_vote_for_self
        if voter_id == voted_id
        errors.add(:vote, "You cannot vote for your self")
        end
    end
```

Set the `flash message` in controller action as below:

```
  def create
        @imagevote = Imagevote.new(imagevote_params)
        @collection = Collection.find(params[:imagevote][:collection_id])
        @imagevote.voted_id = @collection.user_id
        if @imagevote.save
            flash[:success] = "Vote accepted."
            redirect_to @imagevote
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Vote not accepted."
            flash[:alert] << @imagevote.errors[:vote].first unless @imagevote.errors[:vote].nil?
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end
```

Comment: Is it possible to add them to the flash hash? That's where I'd prefer them.

Comment: That's getting a lot closer. It now has two flash messages one on top of the other. Is it not possible to append the :vote error to the :success flash? Also it is showing ["You cannot vote for your self"] with square braces and quotes.

Comment: Something like the join in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448789/rails-easy-way-to-add-more-than-one-flashnotice-at-a-time

Comment: See the updated answer. Just append the error message to the existing flash.

Comment: Its a failure message. I renamed `:success` to `:alert`

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly perfect. Just what I wanted. You're my hero today Kirti.