# Flash[:error] add more than one at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use 'nokogiri' among others to check the schema from some uploaded xml's. And i will print out all errors which occurs:

```
    xsd.validate(doc).each do |error|
      flash[:error] = error.message 
    end
```

If I do so, I see only the last added error, if more than one exists.

I find also find a similar question, about this problem [rails-easy-way-to-add-more-than-one-flashnotice-at-a-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448789/rails-easy-way-to-add-more-than-one-flashnotice-at-a-time/) but the accepted solution dosen't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: `flash[:error]` is (essentially) a hash value, keyed by `:error`. If you want to put multiple values in it then you need to collect them under that key, and adjust the view layer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the method to

```
flash[:error] = xsd.validate(doc).map(&:message).to_sentence
```

**UPDATE**

Using `br` tags to separate each error

```
flash[:error] = xsd.validate(doc).map(&:message).join('<br>').html_safe
```

Comment: Is there a way to put every message in a separated line?

Comment: hey @dot, i've updated the answer so the errors are joined using break tags

Answer (score 0):

> I find also find a similar question, about this problem
>   rails-easy-way-to-add-more-than-one-flashnotice-at-a-time but the
>   accepted solution dosen't work for me.

In what way doesn't it work for you?

You can add your own flash types like flash[:errors] and write your own helper methods for convenience.

```
def my_flash(type, message)
  flash[type] ||= []
  flash[type] += Array.wrap(message)
end
```

Then you can use an array or a string as the message, making it easy to pass multiple in, like so.

```
my_flash :errors, "name cannot be blank"
my_flash :errors, ["age must be greater than 17", "phone number is invalid"]

p flash[:errors]
#=> ["name cannot be blank", "age must be greater than 17", "phone number is invalid"]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me in a way thant i get always the Template::Error (undefined method 'html_safe' for #<Array:0x..>>, if i add more than one flash in a row or a array